# Why can't I move focus to a button in iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, safari

I've got a navigation menu written in Angular that has its own slide-in sub-menu. When the sub-menu is closed I need to manually move screen-reader/keyboard focus back to the menu button that opened that sub-menu. But on most of the iOS simulators I'm testing on (e.g. iPhone 12 Pro Max, iOS 16.5) it's ignoring my focus call and just planting focus on the nearest element.

I've heard of 'user intent' and tried triggering a touch event but it's not made difference yet.

[image: Diagram of the first and second states of the sub-menu]

Unfortunately the real designs and screenshots have to be redacted.

```js
    openSubnav(): void {
      this.previousActiveElement = document.activeElement as HTMLElement;
      this.subnavOpen = true;
      this.collapsed = false;
      this.focusTitle.next();
    }
    closeSubnav(): void {
      if (this.subnavOpen) {
        this.subnavOpen = false;
        this.previousActiveElement.focus();
      }
    }
```